# How to prevent writing to the same file Python

Tags: python, overwrite

I'm scraping a site and saving images to my local. This is working well but some images have different paths but same exact name so they get overwritten in my local even do they are different images.

How can I save all images without overwriting previous ones. I'm thinking of adding a counter prefix to each image name but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the code:

```
    # Save images
    for url in urls:
    filename = re.search(r'([\w_-]+[.](jpg|gif|png))$', url)
    filename = re.sub(r'\d{4,}\.', '.', filename.group(0))

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        if 'http' not in url:
            # sometimes an image source can be relative
            # if it is provide the base url which also happens
            # to be the site variable atm.
            hostname = urlparse(site).hostname
            scheme = urlparse(site).scheme
            url = '{}://{}/{}'.format(scheme, hostname, url)

        # for full resolution image the last four digits needs to be striped
        url = re.sub(r'\d{4,}\.', '.', url)

        print('Fetching image from {} to {}'.format(url, filename))
        response = requests.get(url)
        f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: just add a timestamp with name of the file. That will make them unique

Comment: Just add each filename to a set each time you write to it and check the set for membership of future file names before proceeding with a write.

Comment: Could you not just use tempfile.mkdtemp?
 https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a method as:

```
import datetime

def timeStamped(fname, fmt='%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S_{fname}'):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)
```

Open the file as follows:

```
with open(timeStamped(filename),'w') as f:
```

Write the data as:

```
f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a timestamp to your file

```
import datetime
import os.path

if os.path.isfile(fname):
    t = datetime.datetime.now()
    fname += t.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: I get how I could just change the filename but .write takes response.content as parameter where response is the request url

Comment: is `response = requests.get(url+"_duplicate")` working? Somehow?